# Recycle View setOnClick

Tags: java, android

i trying to pass my data to another activity...and i using recycle view..may i know what is the error here...when i click my recycle view it has stopped...[This is my java code for recycle view adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai2Jo.png)

[My LogCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv6nG.png)

Comment: Please post logcat

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'stopped'? Could you share the Logcat?

Comment: sorry for that my logcat is here..can take a look :(

Comment: LOGCAT LINK :https://imgur.com/a/b9pHh

Comment: @seetohchunyip post your logcat as text not as a image

Comment: you didn't type cast views by id in MyAdapter.java file and the code provided by you didn't show any onclick action in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener((view) ->
  Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Comment.class)
```

Explanation: Generally you pass wrong context (non-activity context) to intent. And you have 2 options: use correct context or set flag in Manifest as suggested in stack-trace.

Comment: owh~~ thx a lot ... problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create interface onclick:

```
public interface OnClicker{
  void onRecyclerClickListener(Bundle bundle);
}
```

Make `startActivityForResult();` put click listern of recycler inside viewHolder`s view inflated. After that call object method of above interface from overriden result of start activity of activity and pass data to the next activity via bundle

Implement interface inside your activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{}
```